# Как использовать OpenCL в программе?

Tags: c++, opencl

Загрузил AMD SDK. в папке **\include\SDKUtil**
лежат куча *.hpp файлов. Как работать с OpenCL что подключать? 
В интернете крайне мало информации.

Comment: lib-файл подключите. А по OpenCL даже книги какие-то были...

Comment: Дело в том, то что есть это 2009-2011 года. О старых версиях. А в новых версиях кажется уже не __kernel а __kernel_program(кажется так). Версии обновились а информация устарела.

Comment: Я им занимался году этак в 13-м и все было в порядке.